# Polkadot{js} state queryies example not working

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I am trying to run one of the examples in the [Polkadot{.js} documentation](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query) and it is not working for me in TypeScript.  This much works

```
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  console.log(api.genesisHash.toHex());

  const ADDR = '5DTestUPts3kjeXSTMyerHihn1uwMfLj8vU8sqF7qYrFabHE';
  const now = await api.query.timestamp.now();
  console.log(`${now}`);
```

However, this line does not work:

```
  const { nonce, data: balance } = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
```

Here is the error returned:

```
   return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/scripts/index.ts:110:11 - error TS2339: Property 'nonce' does not exist on type 'Codec'.

110   const { nonce, data: balance } = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
              ~~~~~
src/scripts/index.ts:110:18 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Codec'.

110   const { nonce, data: balance } = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
                     ~~~~
```

I don't know if the problem is that I am running it in TypeScript or something else, but does anyone have any suggestions to make this work or see something that I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Your TypeScript is not augmented, so it returns a default `Codec`. See this for the solution - https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I was able to use the following code to get the nonce and free balance:

```
  const data = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(data['nonce'].toHuman());
  console.log(data['data']['free'].toHuman());
```

Do you think the online example is outdated?